# MAX aggregate function with VIEW

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query :

```
CREATE VIEW MOSTACTIVESELLER AS
Select a.* from
(
SELECT a.ownerID, b.sellerName, count(distinct a.ITEMID) as item_qty
FROM item AS a
INNER JOIN seller AS b ON a.ownerID = b.sellerID
GROUP BY a.ownerID,b.sellerName 
) a
```

the resutl of this view query is:

```
+--ID--+--seller-+-qty--+
| 1000 | Nick     | 3 |
| 1001 | Morgan   | 2 |
| 1002 | stancly  | 1 |
| 1003 | chandler | 1 |
| 1004 | chiptle  | 3 |
| 1005 | samir    | 2 |
| 1006 | matuidi  | 3 |
| 1007 | medjek   | 1 |
| 1008 | leo      | 1 |
| 1009 | georgi   | 1 |
| 1010 | bocheli  | 2 |
+------+----------+---+
```

So what I want is use an aggregate function like max to return only the most active seller in this list(ONLY 1) as you can see 3 sellers with qty 3 , i think that max function will return one . if not i maybe order the view DESC and return the top value. but could not make that to work. I tried to use max with the view MOSTACTIVESELLER i dont know how to do that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised your query works in MySQL -- usually subqueries are not allowed in the `FROM` clause in a view. But this should work as a view:

```
CREATE VIEW MOSTACTIVESELLER AS
    SELECT s.sellerID, s.sellerName, count(distinct i.ITEMID) as item_qty
    FROM item i INNER JOIN
         seller s
         ON i.ownerID = s.sellerID
    GROUP BY s.sellerID, s.sellerName 
    HAVING count(distinct i.ITEMID) = (SELECT count(distinct i.ITEMID)
                                       FROM item i
                                       GROUP BY i.ownerID
                                       ORDER BY 1 DESC
                                       LIMIT 1
                                      );
```

EDIT:

I thought `LIMIT` was allowed with `=`, but MySQL has strange limits on the use of `LIMIT` in a subquery.  It is easy enough to replace:

```
    HAVING count(distinct i.ITEMID) >= ALL (SELECT count(distinct i.ITEMID)
                                            FROM item i
                                            GROUP BY i.ownerID
                                           );
```

Comment: Tnx for your reply, though i have an error saying: Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'.?? do you have an idea why its giving an error

Comment: Hmm the query is returning the same result as i had before, also the group by inside the having clause throw an error Column 'item.ownerID' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. I had to ommit the i for it to work, but it produced the same result as had. instead am looking for only one max count not the list, i think we have to ommit the group by if am not mistaken. but i can;t figure out a solution for that.